# Get specific value by key from nested dictionaries/lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to return "blue" only (ignore other colors) from color_menu in this list/dict:

```
{'id': 10, 'color_menu': [{'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Sandra'}, {'color': 'red', 'name': 'Lisa'}]}
```

I am able to return all three colors but haven't been able to isolate and return just blue.

Comment: doesn't `yourdict["color_menu"][0]["color"]` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain the indexes:

```
>>> x = {'id': 10, 'color_menu': [{'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Sandra'}, {'color': 'red', 'name': 'Lisa'}]}
>>> x["color_menu"][0]["color"]
'blue'
```

Note that this is kinda unreadable: only do it this way if you can't reshape the data structures in any way.

Explanation:

- dictionaries are unordered and are indexed (usually) by key, though it's possible to index by value. in this case, the keys are strings and the values are more objects.
- lists are indexed by their numeric index.
- dictionaries inside lists inside dictionaries (known as "nested") are no different: the syntax is sensical.